# For loop in R with panel data

Tags: r, dataframe

Please find below my code. It works, but I would like to optimise this. As you can see I am reading in the data 5 times, subsetting the data based on day variable; identifying different the same values across the 5 days and calculating durations in minutes, hours and based on person number. How can I reduce this code for example in a for loop

```
c <- read_dta("c.dta")
act<-c[which (c$dyear==2020 & c$dday==1),]
activ <-act [, 167:310]

#### ###################


bduration <-0  
bduration  <-ifelse(activ [,1:144] >127 & activ [,1:144] <129 , bduration +10, bduration)
bduration <-colSums(bduration [,])
bduration<-as.data.frame(bduration)

Minutes_bduration=sum(bduration)
Hours_bduration= Minutes_bduration / 60
Hours_bduration_per_tus = Hours_bduration / 338

Duration_Monday=c(Minutes_bduration, Hours_bduration, Hours_bduration_per_tus)


############

c <- read_dta("c.dta")

act<-c[which (c$dyear==2020 & c$dday==2),]

activ <-act [, 167:310]

bduration <-0  
bduration  <-ifelse(activ [,1:144] >127 & activ [,1:144] <129 , bduration +10, bduration)
bduration <-colSums(bduration [,])
bduration<-as.data.frame(bduration)

Minutes_bduration=sum(bduration)
Hours_bduration= Minutes_bduration / 60
Hours_bduration_per_tus = Hours_bduration / 294

Duration_Tuesday=c(Minutes_bduration, Hours_bduration, Hours_bduration_per_tus)



############

c <- read_dta("c.dta")

act<-c[which (c$dyear==2020 & c$dday==3),]

activ <-act [, 167:310]

bduration <-0  
bduration  <-ifelse(activ [,1:144] >127 & activ [,1:144] <129 , bduration +10, bduration)
bduration <-colSums(bduration [,])
bduration<-as.data.frame(bduration)

Minutes_bduration=sum(bduration)
Hours_bduration= Minutes_bduration / 60
Hours_bduration_per_tus = Hours_bduration / 303

Duration_Wednesday=c(Minutes_bduration, Hours_bduration, Hours_bduration_per_tus)


############

c <- read_dta("c.dta")

act<-c[which (c$dyear==2020 & c$dday==4),]

activ <-act [, 167:310]

bduration <-0  
bduration  <-ifelse(activ [,1:144] >127 & activ [,1:144] <129 , bduration +10, bduration)
bduration <-colSums(bduration [,])
bduration<-as.data.frame(bduration)

Minutes_bduration=sum(bduration)
Hours_bduration= Minutes_bduration / 60
Hours_bduration_per_tus = Hours_bduration / 351

Duration_Thursday=c(Minutes_bduration, Hours_bduration, Hours_bduration_per_tus)

############################

c <- read_dta("c.dta")

act<-c[which (c$dyear==2020 & c$dday==5),]

activ <-act [, 167:310]

bduration <-0  
bduration  <-ifelse(activ [,1:144] >127 & activ [,1:144] <129 , bduration +10, bduration)
bduration <-colSums(bduration [,])
bduration<-as.data.frame(bduration)

Minutes_bduration=sum(bduration)
Hours_bduration= Minutes_bduration / 60
Hours_bduration_per_tus = Hours_bduration / 326

Duration_Friday=c(Minutes_bduration, Hours_bduration, Hours_bduration_per_tus)

############


df=rbind(Duration_Monday,Duration_Tuesday,Duration_Wednesday,Duration_Thursday,Duration_Friday)
#df<-as.data.frame(df)
colnames(df)=c("Minutes","Hours","Hours/person")
df<-as.data.frame(df)
```

Comment: Make an effort, take one section, wrap it in a function and use it for the others! Perfect practice field ;)

Comment: A couple of tips: you never modify the `c` object so there is no reason to read it in each time. Also, it's not great practice to name an object `c` because of the base function `c()` (concatenate). Finally, instead of a loop, you could group the data frame by `dday` and apply the same operation to each.